# Error in parse json response and store model class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I have this JSON data:

```
{
    "result": {
        "OrderNo": "23456tr4",
        "ProductOrder": "1",
        "TotalCost": "$300",
        "Fname": "wwww",
        "Lname": "wwww",
        "Address": "wwww"
    }
}
```

And I tried parsing it with the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *data_holder_array = [NSMutableArray array];

if([response isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

    NSMutableArray *tempDataArray = response;

     NSLog(@"tempDataArraytempDataArraytempDataArray %@",tempDataArray);

    [tempDataArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [tempDataArray objectAtIndex:idx];

        ISPandingOrderServiceHelper *temp_Data_Model = [[ISPandingOrderServiceHelper alloc] init];
        [temp_Data_Model setAddress:[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"Address"]];
        [temp_Data_Model setFname:[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"Fname"]];
        [temp_Data_Model setLname:[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"Lname"]];
        [temp_Data_Model setOrderNo:[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"OrderNo"]];
        [temp_Data_Model setProductOrder:[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"ProductOrder"]];
        [temp_Data_Model setTotalCost:[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"TotalCost"]];

        [[ISSingletonClass sharedMySingleton] setPandingOrderService:temp_Data_Model];
        [data_holder_array addObject:temp_Data_Model];
    }];
```

But when I try to run the code, I see the following error message in the console:

```
Error :-[__NSDictionaryM enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x90108d0
2013-10-01 12:39:56.563 InkShop[1688:16c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception`
```

Comment: That's just a bunch of code, you haven't told us what your problem is and you haven't asked a question. Please edit your question and turn it into something that can be answered.

Comment: This is the Error :-[__NSDictionaryM enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x90108d0
2013-10-01 12:39:56.563 InkShop[1688:16c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception @DarkDust

Comment: Well, `NSDictionary` does not have a `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` method. You're looking for [`enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:). Next time, please provide vital informations like your error message, what you are doing and so on right in the question. Otherwise we just don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: Clearly the response is an NSDictionary is being typeCasted into tempDataArray(NSMutableArray) and exception is generated.Did you miss something? like- *tempDataArray = [response valueForKey:@"something"];

Comment: what you are getting in response is NSDictionary and you are assigning it to NSMutableArray..that's why it is giving you an error.

Comment: ok actually i have new ib stack for little bet faceing problem.. thanks. @DarkDust

Comment: I don't see any signs of JSON anywhere.  How does JSON fit into this?  If "response" is your parsed JSON, that's a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.

Comment: here everything is "response" @Hot Licks

Comment: But "response" is not an array.  If you knew how to read JSON you'd know that.

Comment: (And why the heck use "enumerateObjectsUsingBlock vs a simple for loop??)

Answer (score 0):

Line number 3
NSMutableArray *tempDataArray = response;
Assign response to a MutableDictionary.Again you will get another NSmutableDictionary if you take objectForKey:@"result"

Comment: enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: this is the solution of this "response" thankYou @ios developer

Comment: @Abhinav - Admit it, you're using enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock because that was the way the code was written that you copied.  (The same way you copied making "response" an NSMutableArray.)  Please don't just copy -- *understand* and write your own code.